# Does react-navigation v5 supports React Native 72?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-v6

Currently our mobile app version is 68 and we are trying to update our app to React Native 72. @rnx-kit/align-deps tools recommends to update react-navigation from v5 to v6.
But from the docs I do not see such requirement and assume v5 should work with React native 72 version.

We do have plans to move to v6 in short-term but trying to get this query clarified from community.

React Native 72 Upgrade